# Strange behavior from counter variable inside cursor loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL I am using a counter variable to increment a numeric value that is written to the NewForm column. The counter value is sometimes a number and most of the time an asterisks. The expected results are for the asterisks to be the counter value. Why is this happening?

Code I am using below:

```
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @form INT
DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR

WITH FRM AS
(
    SELECT RunlistIx AS Id, Form, TransitDays, Quantity, '0' AS NewForm
    FROM Runlist
    WHERE (UserId = N'095a6c66-238e')
)
SELECT * 
INTO #tmp 
FROM FRM;

SET @counter = 1;

SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Id, Form 
    FROM #tmp
    WHERE (NewForm = 0)
    ORDER BY transitdays DESC

OPEN @cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @id, @form

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #tmp
    SET NewForm = @counter
    WHERE Form = @form  

    FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @id, @form
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;    
END

SELECT * 
FROM #tmp;

DROP TABLE #tmp

CLOSE @cursor
DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

Below are the results:

```
+=====+======+=============+==========+=========+
| Id  | Form | TransitDays | Quantity | NewForm |
+=====+======+=============+==========+=========+
| 961 |    8 |           4 |     7000 | *       |
| 962 |   11 |           4 |     1750 | *       |
| 963 |   12 |           3 |    93000 | 9       |
| 964 |   19 |           3 |     8750 | 3       |
| 965 |    1 |           3 |     5250 | *       |
| 966 |   13 |           3 |    24500 | 8       |
| 967 |    3 |           3 |     1750 | 7       |
| 968 |    3 |           3 |     1750 | 7       |
| 969 |   13 |           3 |    26250 | 8       |
| 970 |   12 |           3 |   101500 | 9       |
| 971 |   11 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 972 |    8 |           3 |     7000 | *       |
| 973 |    1 |           3 |     5250 | *       |
| 974 |    2 |           3 |     3500 | *       |
| 975 |   14 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 976 |   14 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 977 |   15 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 978 |    2 |           3 |     3500 | *       |
| 979 |   15 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 980 |   16 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 981 |   16 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 982 |   17 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 983 |   17 |           3 |     1750 | *       |
| 984 |   10 |           3 |     3500 | *       |
| 985 |    9 |           3 |     5250 | *       |
| 986 |    5 |           2 |     3500 | *       |
| 987 |    4 |           2 |     5250 | *       |
| 988 |    6 |           2 |     1750 | *       |
| 989 |    6 |           2 |     1750 | *       |
| 990 |    4 |           2 |     5250 | *       |
| 991 |   18 |           2 |     1750 | *       |
+-----+------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: I don't see how this code can do that. Is it complete? Also, in your cursor, you update by the Form column; shouldn't you be updating based on the Id column?

Comment: Yes it is complete. I am trying to change the form numbers from what they currently are based on the transitdays column from top down. Example Form 8 has two records listed so their new form number will be 1. Form 11 now needs to be 2 and so on. Hope I am explaining this so you can understand.

Comment: how does your data looks like before this update query ? And the most important question is "why using cursor ?" This can be done easily using a set base solution

Comment: Just like above except the NewForm column are all zeros.

Comment: You are using SQL Server Management Studio? And the data output to a grid? Also, change the default column value from ‘0’ to just 0 and see if that resolves the issue

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you are creating the `#tmp` table with `NewForm` as `char(1)`

```
SELECT RunlistIx AS Id, Form, TransitDays, Quantity, '0' AS NewForm
FROM   Runlist
```

Since you required an integer column, it should be just `0 as NewForm` without the single quote. The corrected query is as follow.

```
SELECT RunlistIx AS Id, Form, TransitDays, Quantity, 0 AS NewForm
FROM   Runlist
```

Also, there isn't a need to use cursor here. It can simply done with a set based query. And for the `@counter`, just use `row_number()` to generate a running runber

```
SELECT  RunlistIx AS Id, Form, TransitDays, Quantity, 
        row_number() over (order by TransitDays desc)  AS NewForm
into    #tmp
FROM    Runlist
WHERE   (UserId = N'095a6c66-238e')
```